# Order an SQL table by year and ranges of years

Tags: sql

I would like to be able to order the results in the following way.

There are two columns, one stores years and the other year ranges, and, sometimes, dates, like this:

```
2017    
2016
        2014–2016
        1980-ongoing
2013
2000    28-27 March
1970
```

At the moment, I concatenate them and order by DESC, Getting this (showing the concatenated temporary column):

```
order by CONCAT(IFNULL(CAST(Year_Pub AS VARCHAR(16)) THEN '' ELSE CAST(Year_Pub AS VARCHAR(16))), IFNULL(Date_Freeform THEN '' ELSE Date_Freeform)) DESC
```

The result is:

```
2017
2016
2014-2016
2013
200028-27 March
1980-ongoing
1970
```

However, what I would like to get is this (imagine that this is a list of activities for a CV or similar):

```
1980-ongoing
2017
2016
2014-2016
2013
2000
1970
```

That is if there is a span of years, I would like to have the ongoing engagements to appear first, ordered by the start year, then have spans of years ordered by last year and mixed with single years. Dates only occur when Year_Pub is NULL and will have to be removed before concatenation, I imagine.

The separator is an ndash, so I need to split those strings by that somehow as I see from examples that show how to order by the family names in tables that have first name and family name in one column but this is a more complicated situation and I am not really familiar with SQL.

Also, this operation will be performed on a table that comes with an application so I do not want to insert data or columns into their database in case something gets broken.

Using SQL on an [ElevateDB](http://www.elevatesoft.com/manual?action=contents&id=edb2sql) database (SQL 2003 standard (ANSI ISO/IEC 9075:2003), but a generic solution will do, I can look up the syntax).

Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Your data seems hard to read and parse. Is `28-27 March` an year range (may be data will have more like `28/03-31/08`, `28 May-01 November`...? You have `1980-ongoing`, so do you have `1990-now` or `1991-keepgoing` or ..... ?

Comment: @Pham Yes, I know, but this is what I have. However, it is always 'ongoing' and it is always '00-00 Month' with no year. I guess, one can presume four characters after ndash to get the year or search for a match of 'ongoing', this should do. '00-00 Month' entries only occur if the year is also present and can be ignored/removed before concatenation. ??

Comment: Ah your comment is the answer for your question. Now you could just write your query for that.

Comment: @Pham :) The problem is I do not know anything about SQL, its functions and principles and it would be good to see how to form it. E.g., how can I delete something from a table only for the purposes of ordering and with no chance of affecting the actual data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to achieve your result:

```
SELECT 
    year_pub,
    date_freeform,
    COALESCE(CAST(year_pub AS VARCHAR(4)), date_freeform) AS year_list
FROM
    table_name
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(CAST(year_pub AS VARCHAR(4)), 
            CASE WHEN RIGHT(date_freeform, 4) = 'oing' 
                THEN '9999' 
                ELSE RIGHT(date_freeform, 4)
            END
    ) DESC,
    date_freeform DESC;
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I shall play with this. One question as I am nervous not to mess up the data, when you do `COALESCE ... AS year_list`, does this just happen in memory with no effect on the source table? So that when I ran another query all will be the same?

Comment: @SR98115 Yes, `SELECT` statement does not change your data in table. In general, it only read and display data in your expected output format.

Comment: @ Pham Many thanks, this works nicely. One other thing I have mentioned it does not do is sorting the `ongoing` entries by the start year, descending. Once I sort all of them to the top as `9999`, how can I do another pass using the left 4 characters of `date_freeform`?

Comment: @SR98115 you may change with my edited answer. But for your addition information, my query now do not sort records with same year, eg `2000    28-27 March` and `2000    01-02 February` (what does `00-00 Month` means, eg `28-27 March`?)

Comment: From what I understand, your code should work for this secondary sorting too, but it does not. I must be missing something. What I mean is if there are many `ongoing` entries, they should be sorted in the descending order, which I think your last line is meant to be doing. But this does not happen, I am getting something like this: `1980-ongoing
2001-ongoing
1999-ongoing
2017
2016
2014-2016
2013
2000
1970` Not sorting the same start year is OK.

Comment: While if I simply do `ORDER BY Year_pub DESC, date_freeform DESC`, this sorts as I expect. Confusing...

Comment: Also, what is this line for? `COALESCE(CAST(year_pub AS VARCHAR(4)), date_freeform) AS year_list`

Comment: @SR98115 that line is the expected output you post in your question. The `ORDER BY` should work for `ongoing`, just not work for same `year_pub`. What is datatype of your column `date_freeform`? Could you change  last line to `LTRIM(date_freeform) DESC;` and check if it work?

Comment: It works for most of the entries, but two/three of `ongoing` ones are out of order. I have checked their data and all seems good. Not 100% sure about the datatype, it is from an application that does not expect me to edit these, I think and I cannot access the actual tables. But I think it is varchar. I tried ordering by `year_list`, which is all cast to `varchar` but the result is still the same. All is correct apart from 2 or 3 `ongoing` entries that are among the `ongoing` block but are out of order within it. `LTRIM` had no effect...